# Multiple QgisFeatureRequest criteria?

Tags: pyqgis

In pyQGIS, I am trying to order features of a layer by two attribute columns, first by "Circuit" and then by "Region," but I can't get the second criteria to register. I believe I am using the wrong notation, and I could not find an example of two criteria being used online anywhere. Here is what I currently have:

```
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy('Circuit',True).addOrderBy('Region',True)):
```

Comment: Actually it looks like it is "working" but the addOrderBy doesn't work for my Region attribute. Any idea why this wouldn't be working? The attributes are floats but I have also tried to convert to strings and integers but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Your example with two criterias is right. I tested it with following shapefile; where I created an arbitrary 'Circuit' field. My second ordering criteria was 'area' (different of your 'Region' field).

[image]

Following code prints at Python Console features id ordered by 'Circuit' and 'area'.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy('Circuit',True).addOrderBy('area',True)):
    print(feature.id(), feature.attribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('Circuit')), feature.geometry().area())
```

After running above code it can be corroborated that printed results are as expected:

```
6 1 127035968.31463054
4 1 196392600.4963259
3 1 213453359.47330928
1 1 280502186.9702289
0 2 138971089.3700023
5 2 144829440.03875843
7 2 162925151.1347428
2 2 373715925.390651
```